# combine multiple textures into one PNG image

Tags: texturing, uv

I need to combine all of my separate textures into one PNG image for a contest, however, I don't know how to do it in Blender version 2.79. It has 18 parts and 18 different textures. Please explain in detail how to combine them, and if possible, send images too. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the model is imported from somewhere else, and it does not allow me to unwrap everything, only individual parts of the object. Even if I duplicate my original, it does not let me unwrap the whole object. I also don't know what baking means, so if you could explain that as well, and how (Step-by-step) to bake my textures into one big texture, that would be fantastic.

Comment: You could duplicate your 18 parts then joint them together, then bake the original 18 parts into the new object, but maybe there's another way

Comment: How would I do that? As I said, I am new to blender, so I don't know how to "bake" things. Could you please give that solution in a step-by-step format?

Comment: You shoul check some tutorials on youtube, much easier to follow in my opinion, keep in mind that in your case you'll need to duplicate your 18 parts and join them in one unique

Comment: The thing is, I have to combine the textures, not the object itself.

Comment: I also Checked on Youtube, but could not find one that really fitted what I am trying to do.